# What does an $\oplus$-sign in the superscript mean?

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation

I've come across an expression $ M^{\oplus n_i}$ in an article and I have not seen this before? What does is mean? The whole expression looks like this: $$\large M=M_1^{\oplus n_1}\oplus M_2^{\oplus n_2} \oplus\ldots\oplus M_r^{\oplus n_r}$$

Comment: Apparently, $$M_i^{\oplus n_i}:= \underbrace{M_1\oplus  M_1\oplus\ldots\oplus M_1}_{n_1\;\text{times}}$$

Comment: Well.... almost, of course on your LHS you're using $i$, so you should have $i$ on the RHS as well, not $1$.

Comment: @don It seems quite apparently to someone who is familiar whith the notation but for someone who first encounters it, it is usually unwise to just assume things, 'cause it can lead you off the tracks completely if you happen to think wrong. Anyway, thanks a lot for the answer, sincerely.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, @gebruiker: did I assume anything or what?

Comment: @don I'm sure your intentions were nothing but good, but the word "apparently" at the beginning of your comment gave me the impression I asked a silly question. No harm done though :)

Comment: Oh dear! How wrong can we be when we don't take into account that we "read" and **not see** the other person! Not at all, @gebruiker: that "apparently" meant that **I think** that "apparently" that's what that article's author meant with that notation, based on my personal experience, and not that your question was silly **at all** ...

Comment: In german, this misunderstanding wouldn't have happened ("anscheinend" $\neq$ "offenbar", instead of apparently = apparently).

Comment: Das ist wahr, @MartinBrandenburg ..I think I meant "anscheinend", as "offenbar" seems to me a little more like "obviously, evidently"...or something like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$M^{\bigoplus n}$ means a direct sum of $n$ copies of $M$. Another common notation is $M^{(n)}$.

Likewise, $M^{\bigotimes n}$ means a tensor product of $n$ copies of $M$, etc.

Comment: And, if you can believe it, I think I've even seen $M^{\times n}$, which seems a little silly to me, to mean a normal Cartesian product of $n$ copies of $M$ (instead of the usual $M^n$).

Comment: Certainly I can believe this because $M^{\times n}$ is used in my thesis (whereas $M^n$ abbreviates the tensor power $M^{\otimes n}$. This is really common when working with line bundles for example ...)

Comment: Yes, completely understandable. I imagine the only reason to use it it to distinguish among other similar notations where confusion is possible. Didn't mean to offend -- still, I think it's silly to use it in the *absence* of such conflicting notations. That's all I meant.